# Hard start and engine stalling

Tags: electrical, automatic-transmission, chrysler, chrysler-300c

What should I do to permanently fix these car problems? I was called to another garage to fix a 2005 300c chrysler. The problems of the car was Hard or no start, red lightning bolt flashing, no throttle response, headlight stays on, immediate stalling after start and rough idle while idling. Old PCM was replaced with a new one however problem still persisted.  I scanned for DTC codes and saw a P0340, P2167, P2166, P2115, P2116, p0603 and more module codes like C2202, U0168, U1414, B1A25, etc.

The major problem is that whenever the red round light probably, the security light, if it remains ON, the car won't start at all however even if it does start by chance, the car would definitely stall immediately.
On the otherhand , if the red perhaps security light blinks and battery light goes off, it will have only hard starting but would definitely start. Firstly, how can I fix the security issue? It's a v6 2005 Chrysler 300 with automatic transmission. The client said: "he doesn't want anything security in the car anymore." How should I proceed to disable that security completely? It's because of that that made the engineer encourage them to get a new ECU.
Please, help me with the repair procedure and also wiring diagram showing power distribution layout identification for the engine bay and rear fuses.  Watch the video below to see what I'm trying to explain.
https://youtu.be/nFA5iHxwX_c and https://youtu.be/omRXM_SU0OI

Comment: What is the voltage on the battery at rest?

Comment: Well, I didn't check but the battery light glew on the dashboard and remaining there.

Comment: The battery level could be at a state where it is strong enough to start the engine, but isn't enough for the electronics to work correctly. When the electronics are trying to utilize low voltage, they tend to do crazy things like throw about a billion codes.

Comment: Do you should have access to Alldata or Mitchell data for online service manuals. A factory security system can be easy or difficult to bypass if its programed to prevent; starter, injector or spark operation using factory remotes. Are you able to separate a factory security issue from everyday starting issues (battery, battery cables and their connections, fuel, spark, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

The  codes could be related to the replacement of the PCM.

B1A25 code refers to Invalid key. The key was programmed for your old PCM and not recognized by the new one.

U0168 refers to lost communication with vehicle security control module. Symptoms are as you describe.

U1414 refers to missing ECU configuration data. The unit doesn't recognize your sensors parameters.

P2167 refers to throttle/pedal position sensor E maximum performance.

P0340 refers to camshaft position sensor A circuit malfunction.

P2166 refers to throttle/pedal position sensor D maximum performance.

P2115 refers to throttle/pedal position sensor D minimum performance.

P0603 refers to internal control module keep alive memory error.

Possible causes : loose battery connection, low battery voltage, open or shorted powe

supply to the ECM or PCM , ECM or PCM programming issue, or a faulty ECM/PCM module.

Answer (score 0):

For months now they issue hasn't reoccurred after it was solved. Problem has been solved!

Answer (score 0):

Both PCM were Ok. Except that 1 couldn't rev the engine but could start it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/70305)